# How to calculate average between 2 joints?

Tags: average

I have $21$ joints (each joint has $2$ coordinates $(x,y)$). I would like to calculate average value to get center of all joints. And then normalize the original coordinates.

How can I calculate average and normalize?

Comment: Just do the component-wise average. What kind of normalization do you have in mind? What should the maximum value / boundary be?

Comment: my coordinates are 0-255 on image space. For component-wise average, you mean the mean value?

Comment: yes, that's what I mean. If you want to normalize the valus, you obviously need to multiply all the values by some constant. In this case, the constant is equal to $255/max$, where $max$ is the maximum value.

Comment: Thank you for your support Matti.

Comment: What do you mean by "joint" ? A vertex of a broken line ?

Comment: Yes, like the vertex points on an image plane.